# calc help: rate of change w/ respect to t of the surface area

Tags: calculus, surfaces, spheres

As a spherical balloon is being inflated, its radius (in centimeters) after $t$ minutes is given by $r(t)=3\left[(t+8)^{1/3}\right]$ where $0<t<10$. What is the rate of change with respect to $t$ of each of the following at $t=8$?

1. $r(t)$
2. the surface area

I solved 1 by taking the derivative and plugging in $t$, so I approached 2 similarly. However, plugging in $8$ into the $r(t)$ equation and plugging that into the surface area equation doesn't seem to be working.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We use something called MathJax here to format mathematics so equations and expressions are easier to read. That's what I did in my edit to your question, and you can find a tutorial to learn how to do it yourself here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It's really easy to pick up, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot plug in the derivative of $r(t)$ into the expression for the surface area. You want the derivative of $A(t)$, where $A$ is the surface area.

The equation of the surface area of a sphere is $$A = 4\pi r^2$$ So, plugging in the expression for $r$, $$A = 4\pi (3(t+8)^{\frac13})^2$$$$A = 4\pi (9(t+8)^{\frac23})$$$$A = 36\pi (t+8)^{\frac23}$$

Now take the derivative of that and plug in $t=8.$

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not using mathjax (gotta learn that), but after doing that I have 24(pi)[(16)^-1/3], which is very different from the textbook solution of (6)(pi)4^1/3. Am I calculating the derivative wrong? thanks, again.

Comment: You did the differentiation correctly. While written completely differently, those two answers are exactly the same - around $9.524\pi$.

Comment: Wow, I feel ridiculously stupid. Thanks, again @RayDansh